# ASP.NET Javascript Error on Input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, validation

My ASP.NET page has an `<asp:TextBox />` whose text input is encoded via `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode();`

The page also contains validators such as `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator />` and `<asp:CustomValidator />` as well as several AJAX toolkit `<toolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender />`

If the user inputs `</` as the text in the textbox, a Javascript error

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected
from the client (ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ucLookup$tbxLastName=&quot;&lt;/&quot;)
```

happens when the form is submitted. I have tried adding various event handlers such as

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e){}
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e){}
protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

and setting breakpoints but none of them are hit, leading me to believe the error only happens client-side.

How can I debug this error? Are there any hooks which allow me to intercept the user's input and filter or encode it before it causes this issue?

Comment: If its javascript error, then try using firebug in firefox browser to debug the javascript or if its in internet explorer, under settings -> advanced, uncheck the Disable javascript debugging option. You should hit the error in javascript where it throws.

Comment: Thanks. Using firebug, the error is:
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ucLookup$tbxLastName=&quot;&lt;/&quot;).

Any ideas on how to intercept the input before it attempts to validate on the client-side? Specifically I'd rather not set validateRequest="false" on all my pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out the suggestions in this thread: [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

For this Potentially dangerous error, you can do the following and see if it helps -

Add the line: `<pages validateRequest="false" />` inside the `<system.web>` section

Comment: Per a comment above, is there a way to do this without setting validateRequest="false"? Is there a hook that fires before the validation occurs that I can intercept?